Why are my petunias dying?
I got some petunias a month ago, but recently they seem to be dying from the ground up. I am fairly certain watering is not the problem, and I have them under grow lights, so I imagine they are getting enough lights. Does anyone think it may be a fungus? I've sprayed them with neem oil.
If anyone has any ideas, I would be very grateful! Thank you!


That soil looks very wet, did you -just- water them? If not, overly wet soil can lead to fungal infection. Most plants evolved in a world where all their water came as rain - deep waterings, followed by dry periods where the soil dried out.

Based on your description, it does sound like a potential fungal issue, especially since the plants are dying from the ground up. Often caused by overwatering or poorly draining soil. Even if you are careful with watering, the soil might not be draining well enough. Fungi like Pythium, Rhizoctonia, or Fusarium can affect petunias, especially in humid conditions. This can occur at the soil line and cause the plant to die from the bottom up.

Couldn't hurt to put them outdoors for more sunlight and the antifungal qualities of sun.
